# Log4net not working with NUnit tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, tdd, log4net

So I've done some looking around.  Most of the threads I find seem related to people wanting to run log4net in their actual tests.  Meaning they want log entries in their test class.  I don't want log entries from my actual tests.  But I do want the expected log entries from the code I am testing.  This is my first time using Log4net.  If I run the code on it's own, the log entries work.  If I run a test, no log entries though.  Im guessing it's not initialized properly or perhaps I don't have log4net setup correctly in my UnitTest (in appconfig or assembly maybe??).  This is an MVC 5 application.  Here is a basic example.

Nunit Test (basics):

```
namespace MyUnitTests
[TestFixture]
public class MyTestClass
{
    [Test]
    public void MyTest
    {
        //arrange
        var testVar = @"string";

        //act
        MyProjectClass.Method(testVar);

        //assert something
    }
}
```

so over in MyProject I have (basics):

```
public class MyProjectClass : Controller
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyProjectClass));

    public static void Method(string myString)
    {
        //does whatever
        log("added value");
    }
```

So I've obviously simplified this for the discussion.  But when I run my actual test, my test passes, the values and the outcome are all as they should be.  I just never see the log entry in the log for method I just tested.  Im sure I'm missing something simple.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the app.config for your main project, you should see a log4net config section that specifies the location of the log file.

You first need to add log4net to your `<configSections>` like this:

`<configSections>
 <section name="log4net" 
   type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, 
         Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821" />
</configSections>`

You can then add a `<log4net>` section to the `<configuration>` tag.  Documentation for this can be found [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html).

Comment: So tried added what I had in WebConfig into my AppConfig in my UnitTest.  It still didn't work.

Comment: I didn't do the Assembly though.  //logger
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Web.config", Watch = true)].  Let me try adding that as well to my UnitTest project.

Comment: Make sure you have a reference to the log4net assembly from your UnitTest project as well.

Comment: So I have the assembly and the appconfig in the unit test project setup the same as in my application. Im still not getting log entries but I think it might be because the pathing isn't the same from my UnitTest project to the log file.  In WebConfig (in the app) it is <file value="Logs/log4net.log" />.  So that wouldn't be the path in AppConfig (in the Unit Test Proj) to get to the same file.  Relative pathing is not the same.

Comment: That sounds plausible.  Try setting the value to a fixed path and see if the log file gets created that way.

Comment: I put in the absolute path in the test proj.  No dice.  But when debugging I can see since this line is outside the method Im calling ("private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(StaticsController));") I don't think my Logger ever gets initialized.  But I've tried initializing the logger in my UnitTest class as well.  Still didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add the above answer.  In addition to setting the appconfig in your UnitTest the same as your Application webconfig (editing the value for log file location if you want) you also need to add the assembly entry as you would have for your application already (changing web.config to app.config in my case).

```
//logger
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "app.config", Watch = true)]
```

You'll also need to initialize the logger (at least I did) in your unit test.  So basically I added this in my arrange of my test if wanted my logging in the method I was testing to fire.  Add something like this in your arrange or setup for you test class possibly:

```
[Test]
public void MyTest
{
    //arrange
    log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyTestClass));
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

}
```